# Pull xcom from taskflow task to sensor inside a task group class instance

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I’ve created a task group class that contains a common pattern of tasks I need to instantiate several times in my DAG. I have a task that submits a job request to an API and returns the API response, and then I need to extract the job id from that response and pass this to a sensor which will poll a separate API until the job has completed. However, I can’t get the XCOM pull syntax right.

I believe this is because I need to prefix the task_id I’m pulling from with the group_id but this group_id will be different in each instance of the class I create. Can anyone help me fix the syntax for my xcom pull so it is passing in the group_id of the current task_instance?

```py
class MyTaskGroup(TaskGroup):
    def __init__(self, database_connection):
        super().__init__(group_id=f'register_schemas{database_connection['name']}', tooltip=f'Registering Schemas')

        @task(task_group=self)
        def refresh_schema_connections(database_connection):
            client = get_api_client()
            return client.submit_job(database_connection)
        
        schema_job = refresh_schema_connections(database_connection['id'])
        
        wait_for_schema_job_completion = MyJobSensor(
            task_id=f"wait_for_schema_job_completion", 
            task_group=self,
            mode="reschedule",
            job_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_instance.task_group_id + '.refresh_schema_connections')['output']['id'] }}"
        )
        schema_job >> wait_for_schema_job_completion
```

I've tried a few variations but I can't find the right attribute to get the group id:

- `job_id=schema_job.output['id']`
- `job_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_instance.group_id + '.refresh_schema_connections')['output']['id'] }}"`

Comment: can you pls try with the solution suggested in this SO thread using f string
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72134364/aiflow-2-xcom-in-task-groups?rq=2
Alternatively, you can also refer to the example in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#the-dag-decorator

Comment: Thank you @subram.  I have tried adding a "name" parameter to the task group and then referencing this with an f string but the template isn't rendering and the sensor is running with the job ID set to the text of the template string rather than the xcom value

`job_id=f"{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(register_schemas_{name}.refresh_schema_connections')['output']['id'] }}"`

Comment: can you also try saving that "name" into a TaskGroup scope variable similar to that SO thread i shared .

Comment: I tried the exact syntax from that SO thread but the dag failed to import with "invalid syntax"

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work this way. In the end I wrote a function to extract the specific field I need from the response of the previous task

```
@task(task_group=self)
def extract_job_id(response):
    return response['id']

wait_for_schema_job_completion = MyJobSensor(
    task_id=f"wait_for_schema_job_completion", 
    task_group=self,
    mode="reschedule",
  job_id=extract_job_id(refresh_schema_connections(get_first_conn(database_connections)))
)
```